# Which of lxml and libxml2 is better for parsing malformed html in Python?

Tags: python, html-parsing, lxml, libxml2

Which one is better and more useful for malformed html?
I cannot find how to use libxml2.

Thanks.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

In the [libxml2 page](http://xmlsoft.org/python.html) you can see this note:

> Note that some of the Python purist dislike the default set of Python bindings, rather than complaining I suggest they have a look at lxml the more pythonic bindings for libxml2 and libxslt and check the mailing-list.

and in the [lxml](http://lxml.de/) page this other one:

> The lxml XML toolkit is a Pythonic binding for the C libraries libxml2 and libxslt. It is unique in that it combines the speed and XML feature completeness of these libraries with the simplicity of a native Python API, mostly compatible but superior to the well-known ElementTree API.

So essentially, with `lxml` you get exactly the same functionality, 
 but with a a pythonic API compatible with the `ElementTree` library in the standard library (so this means the standard library documentation will be useful to learn how to use `lxml`). That's why, `lxml` is preferred over `libxml2` (even when the underlying implementation is the same one).

Edit: Having said that, as other answers explain, to parse malformed html your best option is to use [`BeautifulSoup`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/). One interesting thing to note is that, if you have installed `lxml`, `BeautifulSoup` will use it as explained in the [documentation](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#be-sure-to-install-a-good-parser) for the new version:

> If you don’t specify anything, you’ll get the best HTML parser that’s installed. Beautiful Soup ranks lxml’s parser as being the best, then html5lib’s, then Python’s built-in parser.

Anyway, even if `BeautifulSoup` uses `lxml` under the hood, you'll be able to parse broken `html` that you can't parse with `xml` directly. For example:

```
>>> lxml.etree.fromstring('<html>')
...
XMLSyntaxError: Premature end of data in tag html line 1, line 1, column 7
```

However:

```
>>> bs4.BeautifulSoup('<html>', 'lxml')
<html></html>
```

Finally, note that `lxml` also provides an interface to the old version of `BeautifulSoup` as follows:

```
>>> lxml.html.soupparser.fromstring('<html>')
<Element html at 0x13bd230>
```

So at the end of the day, you'll probably be using `lxml` and `BeautifulSoup` anyway. The only thing you've got to choose is what's the API that you like the most.

Answer (score 2):

Try beutifulsoup instead. It is aimed at parsing poorly structured data.

http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup

http://lxml.de/elementsoup.html

Answer (score 1):

[BeautifulSoup](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/BeautifulSoup) is good to parse the html. You can check its example and find that its good compare to the others.

Answer (score 0):

lxml is the one that's generally recommended. Specifically, lxml.html (if I recall correctly).

I believe it makes use of libxml2 under-the-hood, but falls back to beautifulsoup if the html is particularly nasty, but don't take my word for it, check out the website! ( http://lxml.de/ )